# Stop Hazelcast from adding members to cluster on port 5702, 5703 and 5704

Tags: hazelcast

I have the following Hazelcast XML

```
   <network>
      <join>
         <multicast enabled="false" />
         <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member-list>
               <member>11.7.120.10:5701</member>
               <member>11.7.120.11:5701</member>
            </member-list>
         </tcp-ip>
      </join>
   </network>
```

When I look at the members I expect to see 2 but get 6.

```
Members {size:6, ver:14} [
    Member [11.7.120.10]:5701 - 9bb6c4b3-4ef2-43fd-942b-c8e3302b9358
    Member [11.7.120.10]:5702 - f1b5f642-5622-469b-accf-76b25400da81
    Member [11.7.120.11]:5701 - f63c6425-bd6e-4f04-bb7c-8e30bd383be6
    Member [11.7.120.11]:5702 - d1e09d56-ada6-41d8-81d9-3301bf23239d
    Member [11.7.120.10]:5704 - e8f1c922-4b8e-4f5f-bc5f-63ad8c6421bd
    Member [11.7.120.11]:5703 - a9f6da4a-599a-460c-9c22-a1117cb6d970 this
]
```

But in there are members from ports 5702, 5703 and 5704. Reading the documentation I can see that Hazelcasts by default looks into these ports. But I only want the members from 5701 to be on this port. So I only want 2 members not 6. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of Hazelcast is to let other members join the cluster. For scaling, you may add more members and might not know their IP addresses in advance (eg. on cloud).

For `member-list` sections specifies some places a member should probe to find a cluster when it starts. It doesn't need to be all the places the cluster members may exist, and crucially is just places to try *not* places to permit.

If you need to restrict which processes can join, this needs the security module in the commercial edition.

Comment: what about adding the auto-increment option? I tried setting it to false but got the following error when trying to start the process

Comment: ERROR [AddressPicker:main]         [LOCAL] [dev] [3.12.10] Cannot bind to a given address: /11.7.120.11. Hazelcast cannot start. Port [5701] is already in use and auto-increment is disabled.

Comment: additionally I see this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958465/why-hazelcast-tries-to-connect-to-another-two-ports so it seems possible I did the same by setting auto increment to false. Is my understandin incorrect here of auto increments purpose? By setting it to false I assume Hazelcast stops looking at 5702 and 5703

Comment: `auto-increment` limits the port the new process will use. `member-list` is some places to try to find other processes (ie. outbound discovery). Neither stop inbound discovery, other processes joining the cluster. In open source, so long as the cluster name is correct a process is allowed to join. Why not configure the two processes you want with a cluster name different from default and different from the others you don't want.